# Can't use Syncfusion assembly in project

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, syncfusion, uwp-xaml

I tried to use this code, to include Syncfusion Charts to the project

```
xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Charts;assembly=Syncfusion.SfChart.UWP"
```

but I get an error:

> Undefined type "SfChart" in XML namespace "clr-namespace:Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Charts;assembly=Syncfusion.SfChart.UWP"

If I use standard using everything ok, but app package is too big, I don't need all controls from Syncfusion SDK.

```
xmlns:charting="using:Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Charts"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine with the following namespace while using assembly **Syncfusion.SfChart.UWP**

```
xmlns:charting="using:Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Charts"
```

Regards,

Jessie

Comment: Yes, I know. But, can I include to the project just Charts library instead all SDK? Because project with SDK included is bigger at least for 100MB...

Comment: Yes, you can include Chart library alone.

Comment: Are you getting any build error? If so please post the error message here.

Comment: Problem solved. I just have added reference to dll from this path "[Installed Location]\Syncfusion\Essential Studio\[version]\Assemblies for Universal Windows\10.0\Syncfusion.SfChart.UWP.dll" and everything allright

Comment: Thank you SYL, it is very helpfull. Solved my problem with .net native compiler